# deque creation from vector class in python

Tags: python, deque

I define a deque and insert a vector in it in python.My goal was define a deque from vectors.
But when I iterate on this queue,python returns first argument of this vector.
How can I define a deque from vector?

Comment: What's a "vector"?  Please be specific on what you think you mean when you say "vector" in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by `vector`, but, as with about any sequence in Python you are able to store any type of object in it. Unlike C++, where the type of the stored objects needs to be known at compile time.

Here is an example:

```
class vector(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a vector, for realz!"

...

mydeque = deque()
for i in range(1, 20):
    mydeque.append(vector())

for vec in mydeque:
    print(vec)
```